# Solapamiento de puertos de TOR + BurpSuite

Tags: windows10

Buenos días,

Estoy intentando interceptar trafico del navegador TOR a través del proxy de BurpSuite.

Mi configuración en el navegador TOR es la siguente:

Opciones>avanzado>Red>Settings>
Selecciono Configurar Proxy Manual, añadiendo:

HTTP Proxy: 127.0.0.1 Port: 8080

SOCKS host: 127.0.0.1 Port: 9150

Y la configuración en Burp sería:

En la pestaña de opciones:

SOCKS Proxy--> añado 127.0.0.1:9150 (seleccionando "Use SOCKS proxy" y "do DNS lookups over SOCKS proxy")

Y en la pestaña de Proxy>Opciones:

Proxy listeners --> 127.0.0.1:8080

Aquí radica uno de mis problemas, ya que si en proxy Listeners pusiera el puerto 9150 me salta una alerta de Brup con el siguiente error:

Failed to start proxy service on 127.0.0.1:9150. Check whether another service is already using this port.

Evidentemente esta siendo usado por TOR pero me extraña que no puedo poner un listener en ese puerto.

Si alguien sabe alguna manera de solventar este problema , ya que llevo unos días parado en este punto.
Un saludo y gracias !!!